# camera permission for different SDK

Tags: android, camera, android-permissions

I'm trying to create an app that capture some images then send it via email.
My question is :
Do I need to create a different code to access camera and external storage for each API ?!
Because I have created this code and works fine on my phone (API 22):

```
public void startCameraIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takenPicture = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "image.jpg");

    Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(takenPicture);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_INTENT);
}
```

***In this code i'm trying to save the captured image in takenPicture File and save in a specific location in the device.***

When I try to run this code on another device with higher API (23 or 24) I get `Permission Denied for CAMERA`, although I have added the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true"/>
```

Can someone please make it clear to me I'm still learning and I really want to know how to make this code work for any device.
*I made Lollipop my lowest android system when I created the project in the first time.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Marshmallow, all permissions are implicitly granted at install. But on API 23 and up need to explicitly ask the user for the permissions you need at runtime.

Here is a sample from the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA)

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: So does this mean if you are developing for API 23 and up you don't need to add permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?